# What is the best method to return smmry api request with block of text in json instead of url?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, smmry

I am trying to write a function in python that returns the json from a request to the smmry API. I was able to get it working with the SM_URL request like this:

```
def summry():
    API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.smmry.com"
    API_KEY = "B..."

    params = {
        "SM_API_KEY":API_KEY,
        "SM_URL":"https:..."
    }

    r = requests.get(url=API_ENDPOINT, params=params)
    return r.json()
```

However, I am not sure how you would do this for passing in a block of text instead of a URL. I have tried making the request with `sm_api_input=my_input` but that returned an error of insufficient variables. I have also tried it with a POST request and got the same error.

Comment: The description of the API at https://smmry.com/api doesn't discuss any alternatives to passing a URL.

Comment: Does smmry.com support [data URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)? E.g., `data:,this is my block of data to summarize`.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure but I think it does because if you look at the PHP example that they give on the API page they use sm_api_input as follows `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "sm_api_input=".$text);` But I'm not sure how this can be translated into Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is curious, this is how I solved the problem. Turns out I needed an Expect: 100-continue header and the sm_api_input is a separate post field instead of a get query.

```
def summry(text):
    API_KEY = "B..."
    API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.smmry.com"

    data = {
        "sm_api_input":text
    }
    params = {
        "SM_API_KEY":API_KEY
    }
    header_params = {"Expect":"100-continue"}
    r = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, params=params, data=data, headers=header_params)

    return r.json()
```